# TypeError: glob pattern string required when i try to pipe bootstrap

Tags: gulp

I am trying to pipe bootstrap and font awesome but i am getting this error.
here is my task for the bootstrap

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(sassSources + '/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'compressed',
            loadPath: [
                'components/sass/',
                bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets',
                bowerDir + '/fontawesome/scss',
            ]
        })
            .on("error", notify.onError(function (error) {
                return "Error: " + error.message;
            })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'css'));
});
```

the error i am getting  : TypeError: glob pattern string required

Comment: We need to see your sassSources and outputDir.

Comment: `sassSources = ['components/sass/style.scss'];
 
if (env === 'development') {
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
    sassStyle = 'expanded';
} else {
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
    sassStyle = 'compressed';


}`